# Angular 4 Creating Project

Tags: angular, git, github

I created angular project with ng new firstproject , and created some component but there showing letter 'M' in front of some file in directory like app.component.html, app.component.js, app.module.ts. How i remove that M
And in front of node_modules folder showing Green dot , how I remove that green dot, there is not any error.

And why node_modules folder colour is Green?

Last time I use github in node project, that git is continue in angular project, how I remove git from angular project, Help me

**What is the command to remove git directory form angular project folder ? please help me**

*I posted screenshot of angular dirctory*

[image: Directory Picture]

Its the problem of github , help me

**Following error occure after i use  rd /s /q .git this command**
[image: Error Picture]

Comment: Those are some kind of features of Vscode. Run your code and check is there any errors there ? If it works fine then your code is ok

Comment: its a indicator  to notify you a modification done on that file

Answer (score 0):

Those are status of `Git` and VS Code provides indicator of them.

Remove `.git` directory in your working directory. Then those indicators will be gone.

`.git` directory is hidden by default. You need to set a configuration to see it. Or you can delete by CLI.

Run below command in your working directory.

Windows CMD

```
rd /s /q .git
```

Windows PowerShell

```bsh
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .git
```

Mac / Linux

```sh
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: How i remove .git? What is the command to remove git directory form angular project folder ? please help me

Comment: @pune If you are using Mac, then run `rm -rf .git`

Comment: i updated my question ,pls see error msg after use >rd /s /q .git this command

Comment: @pune You are using PowerShell. Try `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .git`

Comment: @zamg sorry i not get what you say, but i fire > Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .git  this command nothing any happen

Comment: @pune I guess it worked. Refresh explorer pane in VS Code.

Comment: Thank You so much Great man @zmag its working... You are great